# Androidx ConstraintLayout does not allow its children to be moved around or have their constraints edited

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I am using the new androidx libraries and the `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout` component is not allowing its children to be dragged around in the palette and does not show the ability to edit the  constraints of its children.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddNewPlayer">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player_name_field"
        android:hint="Player Name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the gradle info:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

Has anyone else had this issue? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

My reddit question was answered by someone on the ConstraintLayout team - apparently there is an issue with version 1.1.1 of the library, and using 1.1.0 solves the problem.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8qaaye/help_androidx_constraintlayout_does_not_allow_its/e0hz5mv

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by Cleaning project and Invalidate Cache, Restart